# Call to undefined function db_affected_rows()

Tags: 7

D6 module https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_dependent_attributes is converted to D7 here: http://dupgrade.com/ and I found out db_affected_rows() was removed from D7.

I tried few codes, basically copy and paste, based on this answer [db_affected_rows gives fatal error in drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/db-affected-rows-gives-fatal-error-in-drupal-7). Now I have a different error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object.

Code which throws Call to undefined function db_affected_rows()

```
function uc_dependent_attributes_uc_product_adjustments_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  foreach ($form_state['values']['body'] as $value) {
    if (!$value['enabled']) {
     db_update('uc_dependent_attributes')->fields(array(
        'enabled' => 0,
      ))->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['nid'])->condition('combination', $value['combo_array'])->execute();
      if (!db_affected_rows()) {
       db_insert('uc_dependent_attributes')->fields(array(
          'nid' => $form_state['values']['nid'],
          'combination' => $value['combo_array'],
          'enabled' => 0,
        ))->execute();
      }
    }
    else {
      db_delete('uc_dependent_attributes')->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['nid'])->condition('combination', $value['combo_array'])->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Changed: This gives 'Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object' error.

```
function uc_dependent_attributes_uc_product_adjustments_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  foreach ($form_state['values']['body'] as $value) {
    if (!$value['enabled']) {
     $result = db_update('uc_dependent_attributes')->fields(array(
        'enabled' => 0,
      ))->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['nid'])->condition('combination', $value['combo_array'])->execute();
      $affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
      if ($affected_rows!=0) {
        db_insert('uc_dependent_attributes')->fields(array(
          'nid' => $form_state['values']['nid'],
          'combination' => $value['combo_array'],
          'enabled' => 0,
        ))->execute();
      }
    }
    else {
      db_delete('uc_dependent_attributes')->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['nid'])->condition('combination', $value['combo_array'])->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change db_affected_rows() to D7 properly?

Comment: Similar: [Error while moving Drupal moving error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17743806/55075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens `UpdateQuery::execute()` returns

> The number of rows affected by the update.

So instead of:

```
$result = db_update('uc_dependent_attributes')->fields(array(
  'enabled' => 0,
))->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['nid'])->condition('combination', $value['combo_array'])->execute();
$affected_rows = $result->rowCount();
if ($affected_rows!=0) {
```

use:

```
...
$affected_rows = db_update('uc_dependent_attributes')
  ->fields(array('enabled' => 0))
  ->condition('nid', $form_state['values']['nid'])
  ->condition('combination', $value['combo_array'])
  ->execute();

if ($affected_rows == 0) {
...
```

(there's also a small fix to the conditional logic)

Comment: In general Clive you're right. But `RETURN_AFFECTED` [src](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/class/UpdateQuery/7) may not always return updated rows depending upon the schema configuration. Things like INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY and also Updates to rows with identical values will not return a necessarily meaningful value for `$affected_rows` http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php  I'm basically putting this as a comment as a public service announcement that rowCount() and its kin may be misleading.

Comment: i can save adjustment form in 'node/7/edit/adjustments' now without the above errors.  thank you both for your time.